# how to avoid "(not responding)" in TForm.Caption?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

In the main VCL thread I run a script that can take minutes to execute (it is a restore database script).

In case the user clicks on the UI I have the "not responding" in form caption.

`Application.ProcessMessages` doesn't work.

I would like to add a "marquee progress bar" and not have "not responding".

Is the only solution running the Db script in a thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, putting the slow code in a separate thread is the proper thing to do (probably the *only* reasonable thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David's thread solution is the best answer, and I voted for it. But for completeness, there is an alternative that is sometimes available.  If the database engine has an OnProgress notification (callback), this can be used to update status/progress, and in this context, calls to ProcessMessages will work.  Sometimes this is all you need, but it's limited to very simple situations, such as when you are displaying a "progress" dialog, and don't want the user to do anything else until you're done.

Comment: I agree thread is the best solution, anyway thread was also in my question, so this OnProgress idea is new for me and I will invstigate, since i use SQLServer (and from management studio i can see a progresss - in % - as a db is restored), so I just have to find out how to do this with my DAC (SDAC from Devart).

Comment: @user Do you understand all the implications of calling ProcessMessages?

Answer (score 11):

Your long running task is running on the GUI thread and it is blocking the GUI thread. The GUI thread must service its message queue in a timely fashion.

You need to move the long running code to a separate thread. That is the only viable solution. Your attempts to call `ProcessMessages` no doubt fail because they would need to be made from inside the script to have any impact. In any case calling `ProcessMessages` is never a real solution to a problem and should be avoided.

Comment: +1 Would like to emphasise the point that calling `ProcessMessages` exposes an application to the risk of handling an event in the middle of processing another. I.e. the second event could run in an 'unstable' state. This is an extremely dangerous situation to be in. Although it is possible to add ugly code to safeguard against the risk, it's better to avoid the problem altogether.